# Превышение лимита

Tags: php

Что может привести к такой ошибке: плохой хостинг или же плохой код?

Comment: Лимита чего?

Comment: Превышено количество соединений, у меня халявный просто стоит хостинг и когда человек 10 заходит пишет мне такое

Comment: Превышение лимита
превышен лимит обращений к сайту

Запрашиваемая вами страница не доступна
в ближайшее время сайт будет активен.
Вы можете выпить кофе.
Можете сходить в кинотеатр.
Не забудьте проверить наличие новых игр.
Всё обязательно будет хорошо ;)

Comment: вот так пишет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У этой проблемы есть только 1о решение - не использовать бесплатный хостинг.

Такую ошибку php код точно не генерирует =)

Answer (score 1):

Да, это однозначно ограничения хостинга. Наверняка это на сайте хостера написано.